# Display Grouped Address data from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, grouping

I know this is probably something simple, but I'm new to PHP and MySQL development so I'd appreciate some help. I couldn't find an existing example on Stack that I could understand so I'm posting it out there in hopes of some guidance.

I have a database table with address information in it.  I've split the address into two fields, house_number and street_name, and what I need to do is display the information grouped by street name, then ordered by house number.

I've mocked up an example of what I need the page to look like.  It has even addresses in the first column and odd addresses in the second column. I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap for formatting.

```
$address = mysql_query("SELECT id, house_number, street_name, full_address FROM resident WHERE neighborhood_id = $neighborhood_id order by street_name, house_number;");
```

**What it should look like**

[image]

HTML CODE BELOW:

```
<!--STREET GROUPING -->
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
        <h3>ASHTON PARK WAY</h3>
        </div>
    </div >

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6"><!-- EVEN ADDRESSES -->
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18102 Ashton Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18104 Ashton Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18106 Ashton Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18108 Ashton Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18110 Ashton Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18112 Ashton Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18114 Ashton Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18116 Ashton Park Way</a>
        </div><!-- END EVEN ADDRESSES -->

        <div class="span6"><!-- ODD ADDRESSES -->
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18101 Ashton Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18103 Ashton Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18105 Ashton Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18107 Ashton Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18109 Ashton Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18111 Ashton Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18113 Ashton Park Way</a>
        </div><!-- END ODD ADDRESSES -->

    </div>
<!-- END STREET GROUPING -->

    <hr>

<!--STREET GROUPING -->
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
        <h3>HAMDEN PARK WAY</h3>
        </div>
    </div >

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <!-- EVEN ADDRESSES -->
        <div class="span6">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18102 Hamden Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18104 Hamden Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18106 Hamden Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18108 Hamden Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18110 Hamden Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18112 Hamden Park Way</a>
        </div>
        <!-- END EVEN ADDRESSES -->

        <!-- ODD ADDRESSES -->
        <div class="span6">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18101 Hamden Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18103 Hamden Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18105 Hamden Park Way</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-white btn-block">18107 Hamden Park Way</a>
        </div>
        <!-- END ODD ADDRESSES -->

    </div>
<!-- END STREET GROUPING -->
```

Comment: will you kindly share your db table format then it will be easier to give you proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're looking to change here. The **Group By** function is SQL is probably not going to do what you think it should do here. It's generally best used in a context, something like

```
SELECT count(invoicesTotal),sum(invoicesTotal) FROM invoices GROUP BY customer
```

On your database, run

```
SELECT * FROM resident GROUP BY street_name
```

You'll only get back the first record found that matches street_name, which is not what you're looking for in this context.

I think the way you're going out about it now with **ORDER BY street_name, house_number** is the best, and use a foreach to build your table.

Also don't use the mysql extension. Use mysqli extension. mysql is getting deprecated very soon. From a beginner's perspective there is not much difference.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I agree... I think the area I need more help with is on the ForEach PHP side... any ideas on how to display the data? Examples? Thanks!

Comment: This is the way I would do it - http://pastebin.com/8MFtF6nL Always make sure you sort your arrays in your php code as well, even if you've retrieved them in a certain order from your database. This means you code even take an unsorted array, and process it the way you want. Also read my note down the bottom about Nested foreach loops

Comment: Mr Mojo... this is exactly what I was looking for in an answer... you've helped me understand how to split it out and I really really appreciate it.  Selecting yours as the answer!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
$address = mysql_query("SELECT id, house_number, street_name, full_address FROM resident WHERE neighborhood_id = $neighborhood_id group by street_name order by house_number");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help... however, I need to know how to display this data... not just query for it... any ideas? :-)  Thanks!

Comment: Yes.. $arr = mysql_fetch_array($address );echo '<pre>';print_r($arr); You will get the result in array format..